# how to know maven compiler version ?is this same as maven installation i.e-apache-maven-3.1.1

Tags: java, maven

in pom.xml `<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${jdk.version}</source>
            <target>${jdk.version}</target>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>` what should be the version no?,i mean from where i will get this version no?

is this the same i.e mvn installation .

Comment: See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: Do you mean the plugin version? Maybe this helps: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#source

Although the values are not explicitly defined, it follows the convention of major Java releases - 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, etc.